# Orthodoxic notation/style of naming in C#

Tags: c#, coding-style

I have read msdn sites about naming conventions but there is no "ultimate" example showing when use capital or lowerCase letters.

1. Should I use capital or small letters to name private non-static field `ip`(below)?
2. If it would be a static field should I use captial letters?

**3. Could anyone post an orthodoxic sample of a C# code.(with no C++, Java or ANY other language infuencies)? I am very confused after programming for a long time in Java.**

```
 public partial class VideoStream : UserControl {
        private String IP; //should I use Camel or Pascal here?
        public VideoStream() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public VideoStream(String ip) {
            IP = ip;//it looks weird
        }
}
```

Comment: you should name it as ip. IMO.

Comment: I see backing fields with the `_Variable` naming quite a lot (note the underscore). `_IP = ip;` looks *slightly* less awkward. You can also go one further and do `this._IP = ip;`

Comment: Choose whatever you like most, but be consistent

Comment: @tnw that's as far as I know is convention from c++ or some other languages.

Comment: @Yoda Unsure. Why are you attaching that seemingly random requirement? What does it matter where it came from? It's a convention regardless, most conventions for C# are going to be inherited or influenced from other languages anyway.

Comment: `IP`/`ip` looks wired because the name just not very readable, especially in lowercase form (and 2 letter names are exception in guideline) - just use longer/more meaningful names and you'll be fine.

Comment: The only good naming convention, is the one your team agreed upon. Uniformity is key.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov so let's say `sourceIp` or `sourceIP`?

Comment: Or name it the field and the argument `internet_protocol` to be more descriptive, or as @Yoda mentioned `source_ip`.

Comment: @ja72 That's why I asked the question using _ is forbidden in `Microsoft's` naming convention.

Comment: MSDN guidelines "Do not use underscores, hyphens, or any other nonalphanumeric characters." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229045(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: For properties and methods, heavens no, never use udnerscrores, but for private fields, why not?

Comment: @hatchet Thanks. By influencies I meant stuff like that. I wanted to get reference example of C#.

Comment: Decorate your AssemblyInfo source with `[CLSCompliant]` for best results.

Answer (score 4):

`private` field should always be in *camel notation*. Generally everything that your class exposes out should be in *pascal notation*, so if your static field is `private` then it should be in *camel notation* otherwise in *pascal notation.*

Reference: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229002%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I would refer you to the [Framework Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in general, although to be honest, we do not strictly follow these.  For private, non-static fields, we use camel case preceded by an underscore, e.g., `_myIntVar`.  In your case, it'd be `_ip`.  If you really care about policing whatever conventions you might choose, I'd suggest using [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

FWIW, I don't like the fact that when it comes to network/socket stuff in .NET, Microsoft was inconsistent in its naming.  For example, they use `IPAddress` but `TcpListener` and `UdpClient`.  All of the socket-related code in my project uses `TcpXxx` vs. `TCPXxx`, thus I would've preferred `IpAddress` for consistency.

Comment: Actually the guidelines you mentioned clearly says "DO NOT use underscores, hyphens, or any other nonalphanumeric characters.". Using underscores clutters the code, Any IDEs can clearly indicate what is a class field or not. And if your method is too big to know what is a parameter or a field, refactor it.

Comment: I don't disagree with anything you've said, @Pierre-LucPineault.  However, we settled on the leading underscore for field names in my project.  *The Pirate Code is more of what you call guidelines than actual rules...*

Comment: But if you use [CLSCompliant] code with `_` or other *non-alphanumeric* character, the compiler will complain.

Comment: There is special exception in guidelines for 2 letter acronyms... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
 private string _ip;
 public string Ip 
 { 
   get { return _ip;} 
   set { _ip = value;} 
 }
```

Comment: Although, IP would normally be all caps because it is an acronym.

Comment: @Andrew Not necessarily, if you look at the case of `XmlSerializer` and other XML classes, they do not capitalize each letter. Same with `TcpListener`, `UdpClient`, `HttpResponse`, etc.

In this case, I would suggest `IpAddress` as the property name for clarity, though you will notice that indeed the class is `IPAddress` in `System.Net`.

Comment: @SiLo: Good point... Although I had `System.Net.IPAddress` was in my mind when I posted the comment.

Comment: @SiLo, I so wish they could rename `IPAddress` to be consistent.  I know it's a mole hill, but it bothers my COD (OCD isn't in alphabetical order...).

Comment: @MattDavis `using IpAddress = System.Net.IPAddress;` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Adding my comment(s) as an answer:

I see backing fields with the `_Variable` naming quite a lot (note the underscore). `_IP = ip;` looks slightly less awkward. You can also go one further and do `this._IP = ip;` just for further clarity.

Why are you attaching that seemingly random requirement? What does it matter where it came from? It's a convention regardless, most conventions for C# are going to be inherited or influenced from other languages anyway.

Comment: Using _ is forbidden in `Microsoft's` naming convention.

Comment: @Yoda "forbidden" is a strange way to put it. It's simply not their endorsed method of naming. Like someone else said, it's whatever the team agrees on. so your question is a bit subjective anyway. Do you work at Microsoft?

Comment: No i do not, but I want to stick to their exact guidelines. The question is not subjective. When I program in java I use orthodoxic style for Java? When I program in C# I want to do the same.

Comment: @Yoda It is though because, again, it's whatever the team agrees on or is already set in place.

Comment: It is not that the underscore is allowed or not - it is a matter of what is considered CLSCompliant. If you decorate your AssemblyInfo source with `[CLSCompliant]`, the compiler will complain that `_Var` is non-compliant. This means that MS reserves the right to introduce `_` to designate some additional meaning to a variable and break your current code.

Comment: @lAbstract Great point. It's probably what I am asking for.